# How to solve the error with gatling launcher for jar in gatling scala? when upgraded from 3.7.6 to 3.9.0

Tags: scala, gradle, performance-testing, gatling, taurus

How to solve the error with gatling launcher for jar in gatling scala? when upgraded from 3.7.6 to 3.9.0

I upgraded gatling version from 3.7.6 to 3.9.0
I updated the version in the build.gradle.kts file

```
plugins {
id(“scala”)
id(“io.gatling.gradle”) version “3.9.0”
}
gatling {
logHttp = io.gatling.gradle.LogHttp.FAILURES
logLevel = “WARN”
}
tasks.register(“prepareTests”) {
dependsOn(“gatlingEnterprisePackage”)
from(“bzt”)
from(“$buildDir/libs”) {
include(“${project.name}-tests.jar”)
}
into(“$buildDir/bzt”)
}
repositories {
maven {
url = uri(“Central Repository: 1”)
}
}
dependencies {
gatling(“com.typesafe.play:play-json_2.13:2.10.0-RC7”)
}
```

but soon after that when I executed the build I am getting below error

```
14:23:56 INFO: Downloading: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/gatling/highcharts/gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle/3.9.0/gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-3.9.0-bundle.zip
100% [===========================================================================================================================================================================================] Time: 0:00:18
14:24:14 INFO: Unzipping /tmp/tmpcol8v6jb.zip
14:24:15 INFO: Installed Gatling successfully
**14:24:19 ERROR: Child Process Error: Can’t modify gatling launcher** for jar usage, ability isn’t supported
14:24:19 INFO: Post-processing…
14:24:19 INFO: Artifacts dir: /tmp/artifacts
14:24:19 WARNING: Done performing with code: 1
```

Please help me solve this issue